# AWS Target Group registering 2 targets on same ECS task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

We have an ECS task definition that maps host port (0) to container port 3000 to take advantage of dynamic host port mapping with a single target group on an autoscaling ECS service. Things have been working fine, for over a year, but this past week we've starting seeing some issues where the target group will register two "targets" to the same ECS task, without any changes to our infrastructure.

Task Definition Port Mappings:

[image]

Running Task. Target Group has registered 2 targets on the same container!

[image]

No amount of manual target deregistering/registering has been helping, and the problem persists on any task either manually added or automatically added through an autoscaling policy. We haven't been able to find any documentation on how these targets are registered and why we're getting duplicates. As anyone seen this before? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which network mode are you using?

Comment: the default bridge

Answer (score 0):

Turns out our ECS agent and docker versions were mismatched. Docker 20.6.1 started mapping to IPv6 ports by default. ECS agent 1.55.3+ adds backward compatibility to the network binding in ECS tasks. We were on 1.55.1 ‍♂️